# Add-Migration or dotnet ef migrations add

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

From an architectural perspective:

- How are these commands the same or different?
- Which should be used when?
- Which is better?

Answer (score 16):

Both the commands are used to add migrations and internally both works same and use [EF Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/index).

The only difference is that one is for PowerShell/Package Manager Console and another one is for Console, So you can run any of these two according to your requirement.

**PowerShell**

```
Add-Migration <MigrationName>
```

**Console**

```
dotnet ef migrations add <MigrationName>
```